# ReactJS Text Input with Emojies

Tags: reactjs, emoji

I need to add Emojies in Text Input. I have to show the selected Emoji in the Input Box. How can I do that?

Comment: Hi, can you post an example code snippet of what you've tried so far?

Comment: I have looked around but I found that these example don't show emojis in the Input (Text box) they  show only emojis codes.. like emoji-picker-textfield.. I need to show Emoji in Input box